# SSIS read text file to temp table before reaching ADO NET Destination?

Tags: ssis, bids

I have a text file that's uploaded to a tsql table. It's straightforward, but due to some inconsistencies, I need to upload this file to a `#tempTable` or `@tableVariable`, clean it there, and then uploading it to the physical table.

So essentially, I have a `Flat File Source` that reads the txt file with the inconsistencies, and uploads it to the table in `ADO NET Destination`. If all the columns in destination table were varchar, then I would be able to save it in the physical table, and run some tsql script to clean. But I don't want to do that.

I can also run a tsql script before and after to create/drop the temp table, but if there's a way to do it with #temp or @table, then great.

Comment: Why don't you want to persist it to a varchar table?  That's quite common practice.

Answer (score 1):

If this is something you do more than once, a standard ETL practice is to have a persistent all-VARCHAR staging table that the file is loaded as the first step.

Then the data is inspected for suitability to add to the production table.

This does the following:

1. Ensures bad data stays out of the production tables where it can break things.
2. Allows the ETL process to be standardized and repeatable.  You no longer have to remember how they broke the data last time, you just add it to the logic that promotes from the staging table to the production table and forget about it.
3. Allows the easy transition of the process to someone else, as well as the opportunity for proper source control.

I can't think of a single benefit to using a temp table/table variable, unless you are somehow unable to create a physical table.